# How do i generate random number than recall those random number for using in another equation

Tags: java, random, numbers

I need help in java creating a code that will generate 10 random numbers 
between 8 and 32 (try to use a loop). For each 
random number generated, raise 2 to the power 
of the random number. Display the result to web 
page.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? This sounds like an easy task, please show us what you've done and don't expect us to do the work for you.

Comment: This smells like a homework question. And that's ok, as long as you're showing that you want to learn, and not just get the answer served on a silver plate. There's a good guide over on meta on how to ask homework questions in the best possible way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
import java.util.*;

Random generator = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int random = generator.nextInt(24) + 8;
    System.out.println(Math.pow(2, random));
}
```

This what you were looking for?

Comment: To raise 2 to the power of the number, you can also use `1 << random`.